# setting default selection for listbox?

Tags: vb.net

how do i make it say that on form load, the first item in the listbox is selected?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hi you can use the SelectedIndex Property of listbox for eg.

listbox1.selectedindex = 0

Comment: The default behaviour is that selectedindex is set to 0.  Which would be the first item in the list.

Comment: selectedindex = 1 will select the 2nd item in the list. 0-based indexing.

Answer (score 4):

Using of the selected indix is the best way - listbox1.selectedindex = 0 (since it is a 0 based collection)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the first item is always selected if no other item is assigned to be. If you want to reset it back to the first item to be selected, a better approach in my opinion is:

```
listbox1.ClearSelection()
```